# Mysql error 150 with foreigns keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, mysql-error-1005

I've got this

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beta`.`msg_messages` (
  `id_msg` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `id_user_from` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `subject` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
  `body` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_msg`) ,
  INDEX fk_msg_messages_user (`id_user_from` ASC) ,
  INDEX fk_msg_messages_msg_messages_users (`id_msg` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_msg_messages_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_user_from` )
    REFERENCES `beta`.`user` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_msg_messages_msg_messages_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_msg` )
    REFERENCES `beta`.`msg_messages_users` (`id_msg` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

*And this is my error. These are my user and msg_messages_users tables too. I've reviewed all my tables and i cant see my error. Im working on MysqlWorbench and it generate this erroneous sintax.*

> Error 1005: Can't create table 'beta.msg_messages' (errno: 150).

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beta`.`user` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 87
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

---

```
 CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beta`.`msg_messages_users` (
      `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
      `id_usr_to` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
      `id_msg` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
      `status` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
      `date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
      INDEX fk_msg_messages_users_user (`id_usr_to` ASC) ,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_msg_messages_users_user`
        FOREIGN KEY (`id_usr_to` )
        REFERENCES `beta`.`user` (`id` )
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: perhaps `id_msg BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` ought to be just `id_msg BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`. How can a column that auto-increments refer to other table?

Comment: post the output for "SHOW ERRORS" and "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" please. autoincrement is legal (although it's certainly strange). The problem is in the fk_msg_messages_msg_messages_users constraint creation (if you remove it, it will create the tables)

Comment: 140215 17:56:57 Error in foreign key constraint of table beta/msg_messages:FOREIGN KEY (`id_msg` )
    REFERENCES `beta`.`msg_messages_users` (`id_msg` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.

Comment: i see in my msg_message_users an index for id_msg and their type matches correctly...

Comment: Im a dumb... i was declaring a foreign key in the wrong table..lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im a dumb... i was declaring a foreign key in the wrong table..

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beta`.`msg_messages` (
  `id_msg` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `id_user_from` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `subject` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
  `body` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_msg`) ,
  INDEX fk_msg_messages_user (`id_user_from` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_msg_messages_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_user_from` )
    REFERENCES `beta`.`user` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beta`.`msg_messages_users` (
  `id_msg` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_usr_to` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `status` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  INDEX id_msg (`id_msg` ASC) ,
  INDEX fk_msg_messages_users_msg_messages (`id_msg` ASC) ,
  INDEX fk_msg_messages_users_user (`id_usr_to` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_msg_messages_users_msg_messages`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_msg` )
    REFERENCES `beta`.`msg_messages` (`id_msg` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_msg_messages_users_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_usr_to` )
    REFERENCES `beta`.`user` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

thanks all